# Jinja2 extends not working?

Tags: pyramid, jinja2, meta

This is my base.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        {% block head %}
        {% endblock %}
   </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my meta.html:

```
{% extends 'templates/base.html' %}
{% block head %}

{% if page == 'index' %}
<meta name="mysite.com" content="{{page}}"></meta>
{% else %}
<meta name="mysite.com" content="other page"></meta>

{% endblock %}
```

This is my index.html:

```
{% extends 'templates/base.html' %}

{% block body %}
......
{% endblock %}
```

This is my view:

```
@view_config(route_name='index', renderer='templates/index.html', permission='view')
def index(request):
    return dict(page="index")
```

Extending the body works, but the meta tags are not showing up at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per [Jinja2 documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#extends) on `extends`, "The extends tag can be used to extend a template from another one. You can have multiple of them in a file *but **only one** of them may be executed at the time*."

When you load `index.html` from your view, the templating engine assesses `index.html`. It sees `{% extends 'templates/base.html' %}` in `index.html` and uses the blocks within `index.html` to replace same-name blocks of the parent/extended template (`base.html`).

So `index.html` says to use `base.html` as the skeleton template, but to replace `{% block body %}` in the parent (`base.html`) with its own `{% block body %}`.

Nowhere in this instruction (neither in `base.html`, nor `index.html`, nor the view code) does `meta.html` get mentioned. The templating engine isn't analyzing all the templates in your directory structure to see how it can plug things in. It is only using your explicit directives.

To be explicit about using `meta.html`, you can use the `include` directive (documentation found [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#include)) in `base.html`. Your `base.html` would then look like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        {% include 'templates/meta.html' %}
        {% block head %}
        {% endblock %}
   </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

This would pull in `meta.html` and replace the same-name blocks of the skeleton (`base.html`) with the ones that were retrieved from the *included* template (`meta.html`).

In addition, the `extends` statement within `meta.html` needs to be removed, so it doesn't create a circular template inclusion.